# Stop click propagation on moving element

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, focus, stoppropagation

I have a pesky problem with autocomplete which boils down to exactly this : one of my `<input />` is moving on focus. Now most users will focus this input by clicking on it, and I need to catch this `click` event and stop the propagation before it reaches the `body`.

I made a stackblitz to reproduce the issue: both inputs have `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"`

- when clicking the static input the `click` will be caught and won't propagate
- when clicking on the moving input, the `click` will propagate to the `body` because `(focus)` is triggered before `(click)`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qnyqvl?file=src/app/app.component.html

Is there any way to catch this click event ? I want to avoid any kind of `setTimeout` delay on the focus if possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to catch this "click" event. I logged it at line `23` of `log.component.ts` file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gdm272?file=src%2Fapp%2Flog%2Flog.component.ts#23

Comment: Thanks for your answer, document:click will listen to the body so it's actually too late to catch it there for my use case